# Firebase can I use observeSingleEvent with .childAdded?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an iOS app. I want to get each child of a node one by one, and stops listening once I have got all existing children. Would `observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded)` do what I want? I know I can just call `.value` and iterate through the dictionary, just wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO,  `observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded)` will set trigger on that node that if any child-node is added for that particular reference. Your code delegate will be called.

You need to use need to use below code for getting all child for that node.

```
_commentsRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there is a `children` property

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded)
```

You'll get at most one `.childAdded` event. If that is what you want, then you can indeed use it for that.

Just keep in mind that:

- `.childAdded` only fires when there is a child node, while `.value` also fires when there are no children.
- If there are no children, this `.childAdded` event will fire later when a child is added while `.value` will fire *now* with an empty snapshot.